# intellij uml, two dependency but should be one

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

I try generate uml classes diagram for my code. I have two classes:

```
public class GuiManager {

public void run() throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    //@todo zmienic to na coś fajniejszego, i nie robić tego w pętli -_-
    for(UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info:UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Warhammer RPG Helper");
    frame.setContentPane(new ChooseServerGui(frame).getPanel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    GuiManager guiManager = new GuiManager();
    guiManager.run();
}
}
```

I never use uml, and generating umls in intellij. 
Below is my uml, what intellij generated:

[image]

why I have two arrows?

Answer (score 1):

One of the two dependencies has a `<<create>>` stereotype. This means that class pointed at is actually created. This is an additional information. You might leave away the simple dependency, but it's not wrong to show both.

Maybe there's an option to turn off one of the two connectors in Intellij but I don't know that tool.

Comment: Yes, i can't find this option unfortunately ;/ But thanks :)